# Error on use having with count in querydsl

Tags: java, mysql, sql, querydsl

I trying use querydsl query with having clause with count aggregation but i have the error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: having near line 4, column 1 [select count(distinct logData.ipAddress)from com.ef.domain.LogData logData where logData.date between ?1 and ?1 having count(logData) >= ?2]

By the following code

```
return query.select(Projections.constructor(LogData.class, data.count(), data.ipAddress)).from(data).where(data.date.between(args.getStartDate(), args.getFinalDate()))
            .groupBy(data.ipAddress).having(data.count().goe(args.getThreshold())).fetchResults().getResults();
```

What´s wrong?

Comment: The "group by" clause is missing in the generated SQL statement. You can only have a "having" clause  preceeded by a "group by" clause.

Comment: Do you have an example for me?

Comment: Just an SQL example: `select event_date_fk, count(*) from tb_registration r group by event_date_fk having count(*) > 1000;`